# Do Global Entry kiosks actually need you to carry a document or just rely on facial recognition?

Tags: usa, global-entry

I’ve used a GE kiosk today and was surprised to learn that it never asked me to produce a document. I had my Green Card in my pocket and expected to be asked to scan it at the machine, but it never did. Nor did the CBP agent ask me to produce it.

Does the GE machine entirely rely on facial recognition or does it simply have a powerful enough RFID scanner that it detected the Green Card in my pocket?

Practical reason for asking this question: I wonder if this theoretically makes it possible to fly to the US without one’s Green Card if one is a GE member.

Comment: Facial recognition

Comment: Facial recognition https://thepointsguy.com/news/global-entry-paperless/ The answer to your second question presumably depends on whether airlines accept GE for *boarding*, which seems unlikely?

Comment: @Traveller literally no one saw my Green Card on this trip. Technically the check in kiosk did but it just scans the MRZ from the document so I could’ve had the kiosk scan a photo of the green card or a print out instead. And some airlines let you put in your Green Card data in advance so you don’t have to scan it at the airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies. Sometimes it's just facial recognition, sometimes you need to scan a document. Sometimes it's both.

> I wonder if this theoretically makes it possible to fly to the US without one’s Green Card if one is a GE member.

I don't think so. CBP may not want to see your docs, but the airline sure will during  check-in and/or boarding.

Comment: I flew into the U.S. yesterday without anyone having seen my Green Card. The check in kiosk did scan the machine readable area of it but it would’ve also accepted a print out because it’s just a simple camera.

Comment: Then the airline got either sloppy or they trust you. The airline IS REQUIRED to check your  admissibility into the US, If they deliver someone without proper credentials to the border they get heavily fined. The process varies. For example I have my passports on file with multiple airlines and sometimes that uploaded passport is good enough for them. Sometimes someone still wants to see my passport at check in.

Comment: It was a pre clearance airport.